# How did Jeanne know where Rafe's House is?

Tags: plot-explanation, middle-school

In the movie *Middle School: Worst Years of my Life* (2016), after Rafe has read that letter from his dead younger Brother Leo, his Friend from School, Jeanne, comes in through the window to make sure he's ok, but how in the world did she know where his house is? She hasn't been to his house before?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the movie, but:

Possibly Jeanne went to the school office and asked the secretary where Rafe Katchadorian lived.

Possibly she used a phone book or an online version to check for address of Katchadorians in her school district.

Possibly by chance she knew the address or physical location where a kid lived who moved out and she later heard that the new kid Rafe moved into that house and thus knew where it was.

Maybe her library card has her address on it and she went to the library and asked if Rafe Katchadorian had an library card and what his address was.

Maybe she heard that Rafe lived on a particular cul-de-sac, which would only have a few houses on it, so went to it and read the names on the mailboxes until she came to Katchadorian.

If enough time for it passed in the movie, possibly Rafe told Jeanne his address sometime off screen, or took Jeanne to his house sometime off screen.   There is no need to assume that you see every single event that happens to the main characters between the beginning and the end of a movie.

And it is quite possible the makers of the movie didn't think about how Jeanne knew where Rafe lived but just assumed she would know.